# Find the area of a parallelogram with the following.

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

We are given the vectors AB=m+2n, AD=m-3n.
Where |m|=2, |n|=3 and $\angle(m,n)=\dfrac{\pi}{6}$. Find the area of the Parallelogram.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Do you know how to find the area of a parallelogram given 2 sides in vector format?

Comment: normally yes, but being the only foreigner in the class is hard. My Mandarin is okay but mathematical terms do get confusing and Baidu translate can only do so much on translating problems,  so when I get confused I ask here @CalvinLin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

- The area of Parallelogram is the cross-product of their vectors. Thus, $AB\times AD$
- Distributive over the addition: $A\times (B+C)=(A\times B)+(A\times C)$
- Cross products of a vector with itself is $0$. Therefore, $m\times m$ and $n\times n$ is equal to $0$
- And the last one $A\times B=|A||B|sin\theta$  (where $\theta$ is the angle between  $A$ and $B$)

These hints are enough to solve this problem.

Comment: I know the rules the problem is that the cross product is 5 using the vectors as is but the set answer is 15

Comment: Because $A\times B=-B\times A$ So either convert use $m\times n$ to $-n\times m$ or $n\times m$ to $-m\times n$. In any case, you will either get $-15$ or $15$.

Comment: The thing is you are not considering the direction of the vectors before adding or subtracting them.  So your answer $2\cdot n\times m -3\cdot m \times n=2\cdot n\times m +3\cdot n \times m=-2\cdot m\times n -3\cdot m \times n$

Comment: I am lost, I get what you're saying but somehow I'm not getting 15

Comment: thanks for the help tho @Naman

Comment: I hope you are getting 15 now

Answer (score 0):

I Hope I got the translation right but it is question 4
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4h8zl.jpg)